# android:largeHeap attribute not working?

Tags: android

I added the android:largeHeap="true" attribute to my android manifest, but it doesn't seem to make a difference in my application's allowed memory.  When I run the below activity on my Acer A100 (running android 3.2.1), I get the following results:

```
largeAmount = 256
normalamount = 48
allowedMax = 48
outofmemoryexception allocating the 60mb byte array.


public class TempActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int largeAmount = manager.getLargeMemoryClass();
        int normalAmount = manager.getMemoryClass();

        long allowedMax = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024/1024;

        byte[] bigarray = new byte[62914560];
    }
}

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.temp"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TempActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, the largeHeap attribute belongs in the "application" tag.